# Archive old files to different files

Tags: bash, shell, unix

In past I have used following command to archive old files to one file

```
find . -mtime -1 | xargs tar -cvzf archive.tar
```

Now suppose we have 20 directories I need to make a script that goes in each directory and archives all files to different files which have same name as original file?

So suppose if I have following files in one directory named /Home/basic/
and this directory has following files:

```
first_file.txt
second_file.txt
third_file.txt
```

Now after I am done running the script I need output as follows:

```
first_file_05112014.tar
second_file_05112014.tar
third_file_05112014.tar
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to archive each directory with the archive name similar to the name of the directory being archived.

Comment: @Vivek I want to archive each file in different directories and need one output archived file for one input file.

Comment: Why don't you use the -r option of tar to append each directory to your tar file.  Then you can just run your command once for each directory you want to add.

Comment: Have you considered logrotate?

Comment: @Basilevs sorry unfamiliar with logrotate

Comment: http://linuxers.org/howto/howto-use-logrotate-manage-log-files

Comment: @JohnC I edited question I need one tar for one file I would be each to tar the whole directory but here the directory size is in Gb's and one tar file generated is going to be too huge of any use so we need separate tar files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

`find . -type f -mtime -1 | xargs -I file tar -cvzf file.tar.gz file`

I added .gz to indicate its zipped as well.

From `man xargs`:

```
 -I replace-str
     Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments with names
     read from standard input.  Also, unquoted blanks do not terminate input
     items; instead the separator is the newline character.  Implies -x and -L 1.
```

The find command will produce a list of filepaths. `-L 1` means that each whole line will serve as input to the command.

`-I file` will assign the filepath to `file` and then each occurrence of `file` in the tar command line will be replaced by its value, that is, the filepath.

So, for ex, if find produces a filepath `./somedir/abc.txt`, the corresponding tar command will look like:

```
tar -czvf ./somedir/abc.txt.tar.gz ./somedir/abc.txt
```

which is what is desired. And this will happen for each filepath.

Comment: Can you please explain this a little would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

What about this shell script?

```
#!/bin/sh

mkdir /tmp/junk  #Easy for me to clean up!
for p in `find . -mtime -1 -type f`
do
    dir=`dirname "$p"` 
    file=`basename "$p"`
    tar cvf /tmp/junk/${file}.tar $p
done
```

It uses the basename command to extract the name of the file and the dirname command to extract the name of the directory.  I don't actually use the directory but I left it in there in case you might find it handy.

I put all the tar files in one place so I could delete them easily but you could easily substitute $P instead of $file if you wanted them in the same directory.